# What is the radial direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory

I'm currently in an electrostatics course; and wanting to rip my hair out.

The question says:

A sphere of radius  is polarized such that the polarization at  within the sphere is given by
 = ̂ , where  is a constant and  is the radial position vector from the centre of the
sphere.

It asks:

a) Find the bound surface charge density  and the bound volume charge density .
b) Find the electric field inside and outside the sphere

My question from all of this is what is the radial vector? I don't actually know what it means for something to be pointing radially and I haven't found much luck through web searches.

Comment: This is not a physics question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Thanks, this is where I checked first.

Answer (score 1):

The radial direction points from the center of the sphere towards the surface. Since the sphere is *radially symmetrical*, any vector with its beginning at the center point of the sphere and its end point on the surface will qualify.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The radial direction is somehow like what you think of "radius".

Just imagine a ball:you define the ridius of the ball as the distance from **the center to the point on the surface**

Connect the two points:the direction is just go alongside the line you draw,from the center,to any point on the surface